# android, Read content of 100-300 files from FTP folder... Hangs

Tags: android, ftp, bufferedinputstream

I am using `RetrieveFilestream` method with `BufferedInputStream` in a for loop. I am closing all
streams after processing each file and also adding ftp complete pending command.

Every thing works as expected in my test environment with few files. But in realtime data where there are 200-300 files, it hangs somewhere.

It is not throwing any exception making it difficult to debug. Cannot debug one by one. Any help? 
Here is my code Block.

```
     public String LoopThroughFiles(FTPClient myftp, String DirectoryName)
                 {
                     boolean flag=false;
                     String output="";

                      InputStream inStream=null;


                      BufferedInputStream bInf= null;

                      StringBuilder mystring = new StringBuilder();
                      progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);    


                     try {
                          flag= myftp.changeWorkingDirectory(DirectoryName);

                        if(flag==true)
                        {
                         FTPFile[] files = myftp.listFiles();

                         progressBar.setMax(files.length);


                         String fname="";

                         myftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();

                        if(files.length > 0) 
                        {

                             int n=0;

                            for (FTPFile file : files)  
                            {


                                 n=n+1;
                                int r= progressBar.getProgress();
                                progressBar.setProgress(r+n);


                               fname=file.getName();
                              // String path= myftp.printWorkingDirectory();

                              if(fname.indexOf("txt") != -1)
                              { 

                                inStream =  myftp.retrieveFileStream(fname);

                                int reply = myftp.getReplyCode();

                                if (inStream == null   || (!FTPReply.isPositivePreliminary(reply) && !FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)))  {Log.e("error retrieving file",myftp.getReplyString()); }


                             bInf=new BufferedInputStream (inStream);
                              int bytesRead;
                             byte[] buffer=new byte[1024]; 
                             String fileContent=null; 


                           while((bytesRead=bInf.read(buffer))!=-1)
                           {
                               fileContent=new String(buffer,0,bytesRead);
                               mystring.append(fileContent);

                           }

                            mystring.append(",");

                             bInf.close();

                             inStream.close();

                              boolean isSucess= myftp.completePendingCommand();  
                              if(isSucess == false)
                                  Log.e("error retrieving file","Failed to retrieve the stream for " + fname);

                              }

                            }


                          flag= myftp.changeToParentDirectory(); 

                          }
                        }

                    }
                     catch (java.net.UnknownHostException e) {  
                          e.printStackTrace();  
                          Log.e("readfile,UnknownHost",e.getMessage());

                        }  
                        catch (java.io.IOException e) {  
                          e.printStackTrace();  
                          Log.e("readfile,IO",e.getMessage());
                        }  
                       catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                         Log.e("readfile,General",e.getMessage());
                       } 
                     finally
                     {
                         try {

                          output = mystring.toString();

                          if(bInf != null)
                              bInf.close();

                          if(inStream != null)
                            inStream.close();


                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                 Log.e("readfile,finallyblock",e.getMessage());
                            }
                     }

                     return output;
                 }
```

Comment: Why don't you use `AsyncTask`?

Comment: I am running this function is run in AsyncTask only

Comment: Post some more code please.

Comment: It is not hanging the ui. But just takes 2 minutes or more to process around 300 text files that have only one line of text in each of them. Just want make it run fast. Is there any way? Are there any other Ftp clients other than apache that i can try.